# A function that returns a namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function that takes 2 arguments and returns a namedtuple.

```
Count = namedtuple('Count', 'letter number')
```

The function should return:

```
>>> letter_count('The cabbage has baggage', 'abcd')
[Count(letter='a',number=5), Count(letter='b',number=3), Count(letter='c',number=1), Count(letter='d',number=0)]
```

So far I have:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Count = namedtuple('Count', 'letter number')
def letter_count(x: str, a: str):

    for letter in a:
        letter = Count.letter
        for letters in x:
            if letter == letters:
                Count.number = len(letter)

    return Count
```

But I'm getting

```
<class '__main__.Count'>
```

Comment: 1. `Count` is the name of the type; you need to construct instances of it. 2. `namedtuple` instances are immutable; you can't mutate instances of `Count`, only make them with their final values and return them. 3. Have you looked at `collections.Counter`? Probably closer to what you really want (you'd convert to `Count` tuples at the end if needed).

Answer (score 1):

your need instantiate `namedtuple` with positional or keyword arguments.

besides, Using Counter for count things, it is simple and has high-performance .  your could check the manual for details.

try this:

```
import collections

Count = collections.namedtuple('Count', 'letter, number')

def letter_count(letters, target):
    counter = collections.Counter(letters)
    return [Count(c, counter[c]) for c in target]  # instantiate Count like Count(letter, number)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> letter_count('The cabbage has baggage', 'abcd')
[Count(letter='a', number=5), Count(letter='b', number=3), Count(letter='c', number=1), Count(letter='d', number=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple approach that does not require `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Count = namedtuple('Count', 'letter number')

def letter_count(s: str, letters: str):
    return [Count(letter, s.count(letter)) for letter in letters]

print(letter_count('The cabbage has baggage', 'abcd'))
```

Output:

```
[Count(letter='a', number=5), Count(letter='b', number=3), Count(letter='c', number=1), Count(letter='d', number=0)]
```

This however does not take case sensitivity into account. So `T` and `t` would have separate count values.